# How to unify the results produced by HTML and printer

Tags: html, css

I created a div to simulate a paper in html, which size is 800*1131 (same aspect ratio as A4) with some content including characters, images and tables.

But I found that if I print the div, The result is not the same as the actual format displayed in html. Usually the font becomes smaller.

Is there a way to unify the results produced by HTML and printer?

Comment: You can use `@media print` (media query) to customize the css for printing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Brewal has said, you can use `@media print` queries in your css.

See http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/11/24/how-to-set-up-a-print-style-sheet/

Like so:

```
@media print {

   body {
   font-size:15px;
   }
   /* and so on */

}
```

if your printer/browser is changing the font(size) then you could put some of the same styles that are in your "normal" css into this query.

Comment: Thanks! This website helps me alot!